# What's the closed-form of the sum relating to the DOS of simple harmonic motion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

In order to calculate the density of states of single particle in the simple harmonic potential, we would calculate that
$$
D(\epsilon)=\sum_{n}\delta(\epsilon-\epsilon_n)
$$
where $\epsilon_n=(n+1/2)\hbar\omega$. In the limit $\hbar\omega\ll1$,we find that
$$
D(\epsilon)\approx\frac{1}{\hbar\omega}\theta(\epsilon).
$$

But I want to know how to calculate the $D(\epsilon)$ exactly by means of some special function for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a formal manipulation that can answer your question using well-known formulas. So, let me write
$$
   \epsilon_n=(2n+1)\epsilon_0
$$
being $\epsilon_0=\hbar\omega/2$ and 
$$
   \delta(\epsilon-\epsilon_n)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{2\pi}e^{-i(\epsilon-\epsilon_n)t}.
$$
Then,
$$
   D(\epsilon)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{2\pi}e^{-i\epsilon t}
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{i(2n+1)\epsilon_0 t}
$$
where I have formally exchanged the sum with the integral (just one of my yet-to-be-justified mathematical steps). The sum is normally not converging. E.g. if we truncate the spectrum at $n=k$ one gets
$$
   \sum_{n=0}^k e^{i(2n+1)\epsilon_0 t}=
\frac{e^{i(3+2k)\epsilon_0 t}-e^{i\epsilon_0 t}}{e^{i2\epsilon_0 t}-1}
$$
that for the exponential becoming $1$ yields that the sum goes to infinity just like $k$. But physicists have a lot of resources to cope with these situations. We can resort to one of the techniques in the [Hardy's book](https://ia600707.us.archive.org/23/items/DivergentSeries/Hardy-DivergentSeries.pdf) and introduce a converging factor into the series as
$$
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{i(2n+1)\epsilon_0 t-\delta n} = \frac{e^{\delta+i\epsilon_0 t}}{-e^{2i\epsilon_0 t}+e^{\delta}}
$$
and the limit $\delta\rightarrow 0$ yields the result we wanted. So, finally
$$
   D(\epsilon)=-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{4\pi i}e^{-i\epsilon t}\frac{1}{\sin\epsilon_0 t}   
$$
that is the final result provided we add a rule to circumvent all the poles arising due to the sine function at the denominator (see below). Just notice that for $\epsilon_0 t\ll 1$ one has $\sin\epsilon_0 t\approx \epsilon_0 t$. Now, you have to add a rule to circumvent the pole at $t=0$ and this is done in the standard way by adding a $i\epsilon$ at the denominator yielding
$$
   D(\epsilon)=-\frac{1}{\hbar\omega}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{2\pi i}e^{-i\epsilon t}\frac{1}{t+i\epsilon}.   
$$
This is exactly the definition of the $\theta$ function and so
$$
    D(\epsilon)\approx \frac{1}{\hbar\omega}\theta(\epsilon).
$$

Comment: Wonderful! It's just the kind of answer I appriciate. Thank you for your help. I accept your answer.